# increase insertion speed in python

Tags: python, mysql, django, time, insert

I have a script in django which i am running on terminal to update the field values in database ,
there is about 3000 records to be updated , it updated but it takes so much time.

Here is the code:

```
getAge  = myplayer.objects.all()
for i in getAge:
    i.age  = i.age + 0.0192         # it is equilant to  1/52
    i.save()    
    print  "new age of id - " ,i.id, "is ", i.age
```

I am using a  MYSQL DB please suggest how can i speed up the insertion time

thanks

Comment: I don't know about python, but seems you are using Python auto update feature, instead simply write an update query like `update myplayer set age = age+0.0192` and run this query directly on db. it is much faster than update one record at a time, when you have no condition to check.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to print new ages, you can do as follow using [F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import F
myplayer.objects.update(age=F('age')+0.0192)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.db.models import F    
myplayer.objects.all().update(age=F('age') + 0.192)
```

Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once